# error while inserting data to a bigquery table in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
Table name "nutrient" missing data set while no default data set is set in the request.
```

this error message shows while i'm running a query in my big query table. I create a table called nutrient and i want to add data to it. So I run a query. But this error message shows and i can't insert data to my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on error message - looks like you are referencing your table with just table name - try to use below notion instead :

```
`project.dataset.table`
```

or at least

```
`dataset.table`
```